# EJB Timer when redepolyed in a cluster environement of Websphere Application Server

Tags: timer, ejb, websphere, cluster-computing

I have an .ear file which is composed of multiple EJB's and one of them do use a timer service to create timer and the same ejb has the callback method too. That ear is supposed to be deployed in a clustered environment of 3 servers. The issue now is that i want to know what is the expected behavior if i redeployed/undeployed the ear in the cluster. Will the server cancel all timers and clear the persistent scheduler? Or it will preserve them? What are the work arounds?

I have read that in IBM web link:  http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.base.doc%2Finfo%2Faes%2Fae%2Frejb_timerservice.html

Currently i don't have the capability to create an environment to test such case and take a confident decision, i wonder if anyone faced such issue before, as this is a very critical issue for me

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EJB timers are not removed when the application is removed.  Some options:

1. Use the `WAS_HOME/bin/cancelEJBTimers` command to remove them
2. Add startup logic to your application to cancel/recreate timers as needed.
3. Use automatic timers (`@Schedule`) in 8.0+.  In this case, the server automatically creates the timer when the application is first started, and it will attempt to remove them when the application is uninstalled.  See the InfoCenter for more information:

   - [Creating timers using the EJB timer service for enterprise beans](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/tejb_timerserviceejb_enh.html)
   - [removeAutomaticEJBTimers](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/rxml_configuringEJBTimerWorkManager.html)

Comment: what is meant by this phrase found in the link:"When an entity bean is removed, all timers, no matter where created, are canceled"????? I don't know how entity beans came in the context as timers are meant for EJB's not entity beans

Comment: This is referring to EJB 2.x entity beans, not JPA entity beans. When an EJB 2.x entity bean is removed, any timers that it created are also removed.

Comment: What if i uninstall an ear for updates. Will that cause the programmatically created persistent timers to be cancelled??

Comment: No, you must always manually cancel programmatically-created persistent timers.